# How to convert TSQLTimeStamp to TDateTime

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I have a table in SQL Server 2008 like this:

```
CREATE TABLE B_INTERVENTION ( 
ID_BI INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL ,
Date_Creation DATE NOT NULL ,
Cree_Par INT NOT NULL ,
D_Arr BIT NOT NULL ,
Obj_Demarrage DATE NOT NULL ,
Obj_Fin DATE NOT NULL ,
Type_BI CHAR (2) NOT NULL ,
INSPECT INT NOT NULL ,
VERIF INT NOT NULL ,
Machine VARCHAR (13) NOT NULL ,
Priorite INT NOT NULL ,
Date_Fin_Trav DATETIME NULL ,
Commentaire VARCHAR(80) NULL
)
GO
```

When I try to set the value of `Date_Fin_Trav` to a `TDateTimePicker` I get ann error in this line:

```
DateTimePicker1.DateTime := FDTable1Date_Fin_Trav.Value;
```

Error:

> [Dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas (53): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TDateTime' and 'TSQLTimeStamp'

So I change the code to:

```
DateTimePicker1.DateTime := TimeStampToDateTime( FDTable1Date_Fin_Trav.Value);
```

Also get an error because the `Type`:

> [Dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas (53): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TTimeStamp' and 'TSQLTimeStamp'

So my question is : How to convert `TSQLTimeStamp` to `TDateTime`?

Comment: @DownVoter at least leave a comment what's wrong in my Q? unclear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`SQLTimeStampToDateTime()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/Data.SqlTimSt.SQLTimeStampToDateTime) function in the `Data.SqlTimSt` unit:

> Converts a TSQLTimeStamp value to a TDateTime value.

Comment: Which is simply a wrapper for the `EncodeDate()` and `EncodeTime()` functions in the `SysUtils` unit